# How to get log and describe of pods in kubernetes by python client

Tags: python, kubernetes

I want to get log and describe of my pod in kubernetes by python client. In kubernetes cluster we can use

```
kubectl logs <NAME_OF_POD>
kubectl describe pods <NAME_OF_pod>
```

But I want these command in python client of kubernetes.what should I do?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can read the logs of a pod using the following code:

```
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
pod_name = "counter"
try:
    api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()
    api_response = api_instance.read_namespaced_pod_log(name=pod_name, namespace='default')
    print(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print('Found exception in reading the logs')
```

The above code works perfectly fine for getting the logs of pod.

To get the output of `kubectl describe pod`, all the information provided is  in `read_namespaced_pod` function. It has all the information you require, and you can use that information in whatever way you require. You can edit the above code and use `read_namespaced_pod` in place of `read_namespaced_pod_log` to get the info.

Comment: thanks for your answer
how can I find more example? GitHub is incomplete.

Comment: I use following link to identify various usage of client in python:
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md

There are other links for other API's like V1beta1, AppsV1 etc.

Answer (score 2):

As Kubernetes is using REST API, which gives you every possibility that you can call logs and description of objects via python.

Firstly you need to find out your authorization mechanism. You can find it via according your cluster.

```
kubectl config view --raw
```

Then you can create api call with this auth method. In below example, I used basic auth for getting pod logs for example.

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
user='admin'
password='password'
url='https://cluster-api-url/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/nginx-ingress-controller-7bbcbdcf7f-dgr57/log'

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
resp = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, password), verify=False, json=False)
print(resp.text)
```

To get the url easily, type command with "--v=8" argument. For example to get url for describe the pod

```
kubectl describe pod nginx-ingress-controller-7bbcbdcf7f-dgr57 --v=8
```

and check above part of your real output

```
I0514 12:31:42.376972  216066 round_trippers.go:383] GET https://cluster-api-url/api/v1/namespaces/default/events?fieldSelector=involvedObject.namespace%3Ddefault%2CinvolvedObject.uid%3D1ad92455-7589-11e9-8dc1-02a3436401b6%2CinvolvedObject.name%3Dnginx-ingress-controller-7bbcbdcf7f-dgr57
I0514 12:31:42.377026  216066 round_trippers.go:390] Request Headers:
I0514 12:31:42.377057  216066 round_trippers.go:393]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0514 12:31:42.377074  216066 round_trippers.go:393]     Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46elRoYUJoZDBUYm1FbGpzbjRtYXZ2N1hqRWlvRkJlQmo=
I0514 12:31:42.377090  216066 round_trippers.go:393]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.12.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/0ed3388
```

Copy URL from `GET https://<URL>` part and change with `url` in your python script, then you go.

Hope it helps

Comment: i do not want use get or post  i want python client code

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers return the events for a namespaced pod, which is given by default when running `kubectl describe`.  To get the namespaced events for a given pod, run:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
out = kube.core_api.list_namespaced_event(namespace, field_selector=f'involvedObject.name={pod_name}')
```

where `namespace` is the namespace of interest and `pod_name` is your pod of interest.

I needed this when spawning a pod and giving the user a reasonable status report for the current condition of the pod, as well as debugging the state of the pod if it fails to progress beyond "Pending".

Answer (score 1):

You need explore https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python Official K8s Python Client.

But I couldn't find any specific docs to your requirement. I think, below link is the start point,

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md

Try to do `dir` on the object and see available methods. For example below code from README

```
from kubernetes import client, config

# Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper utility
config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

Do `dir(v1)` or `dir(ret)` and see methods/vars, etc.. Or may `list*` methods gives you details that you see in `kubectl describe pod <name>`

Comment: that is not I want. this show the list of my pod. I want the log and describe

Comment: That is a example snippet to find what are the methods available to get "describe" & "logs", if there is any. First you have check `list` methods to know what it is giving