# Get status for readyness probe via kubernetes python API

Tags: python, api, kubernetes

if I run

```
kubectl -n=mynamespace describe pod mypodname
```

I get for example this output:

```
  Type     Reason     Age                      From                  Message
  ----     ------     ----                     ----                  -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  43s (x30458 over 3d17h)  kubelet, myhostname  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
```

Now how can I get this via the  python library https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python ?

I can get the POD infos, e.g. using list_pod_for_all_namespaces and get a POD object https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/6d64cf67d38337a6fdde1908bdadf047b7118731/kubernetes/docs/V1Pod.md

but this does only show me (in the podobject.status.conditions property) that the containers are not ready but I get no detailled info like the 404 statuscode above?

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**1)** First of all - you are able to find all the methods here: [CoreV1Api.md](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-client/python/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md).

**2)** Part you are interested in:

```
[**read_namespaced_pod**](CoreV1Api.md#read_namespaced_pod) | **GET** /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{name} | 
[**read_namespaced_pod_log**](CoreV1Api.md#read_namespaced_pod_log) | **GET** /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{name}/log | 
[**read_namespaced_pod_status**](CoreV1Api.md#read_namespaced_pod_status) | **GET** /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{name}/status | 
[**read_namespaced_pod_template**](CoreV1Api.md#read_namespaced_pod_template) | **GET** /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/podtemplates/{name} |
```

**3)** Your right method is `read_namespaced_pod`

**4)** your code taken from @Prafull Ladha from [How to get log and describe of pods in kubernetes by python client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56128463/9929015)

```
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
pod_name = "counter"
try:
    api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()
    api_response = api_instance.read_namespaced_pod(name=pod_name, namespace='default')
    print(api_response)
```

Comment: Thanks. for the link. This helped me to access container logs.. which I was also looking for. However, both (list_pod_for_all_namespaces I mentioned above and "your" read_namespaced_pod) methods return a list of or a single V1Pof object. So the information is the same that I already had. I can not get the readiness probe error I was looking for. I assum I need to work with the events api or so...